# Java extract .cab files

Tags: java, extract, cab

I want to extract files from a .cab file and save them. I could not find any useful information on other questions and on GitHub there is no documentation.

For now I can iterate through all entries (2 text files) with CAB Parser but I cannot find a good way to save them and would appreciate some hints.

```
File inputFile = new File(inputPath);
File outputPath = new File(inputFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());

final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
CabParser cabParser = new CabParser(is, inputPath);
Arrays.stream(cabParser.files).forEach(element -> {
    CabFileEntry cabFile = element;
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 0x44656e6e795279616e = Denny Ryan?

Comment: Yes, from long time ago. Why?

Comment: If these are Microsoft Cabinet files then you could use the [extract.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/extract.html) or the [extrac32.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/extract.html) command line applications which are part of that OS. You can run these from Java in the background.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work with [simple.cab](http://www.geekymedia.com/viewcvs/cgi/viewcvs.cgi/group3/wine/dlls/cabinet/tests/Attic/simple.cab):

```java
final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/tmp/simple.cab");
CabParser cabParser = new CabParser(is, new File("/tmp/simple/"));
cabParser.extractStream();
```

However, it fails with `VC_RED.cab`.

CabParser [README.md](https://github.com/dorkbox/CabParser/blob/master/README.md):

> extract files from within a .cab which are compressed via the LZX compression algorithm

Maybe not all the possible compression algorithms are supported by this library.

One option is to run [cabextract](https://www.cabextract.org.uk) with [Runtime.exec(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).